# How to get only HTML attributes and not the data-store values set by jQuery or other plugins

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-ui, custom-data-attribute

I want to grab HTML data attributes via jQuery using `.data()`.

I need to fetch more than one data attribute, so I am not specifying any parameter and caching the result:

`var data = $('myselecttor').data()`

The problem is that `.data()` fetches not only the HTML attribute, but also the data-store values set by jQuery (for internal use) or some other plugin (jQuery UI in my case).

I need to fetch all the HTML data attributes (excluding the data-store values) in one call (not separately)

Sending this `data()` in `$.ajax` causes an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

```js
var data = $('div').draggable().data();

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div data-name="jashawant" data-sex="male">Drag me</div>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/DprgS/)**

Comment: Why not get the data then filter out the values you don't want?

Comment: I am iterating over a lot of elements have few data attribues , some have others. I was thinking to avoid `if, else`. I am posting them via ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably look at the attributes themselves, but you can also use the element's `dataset`.

```
var data = $('div').draggable().get(0).dataset;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DprgS/1/

Comment: Is this going to work cross-browser ie7+ ? I guess, its a js version of `data()`

Comment: dataset probably wont, but if you deal with the attributes directly, yes.

Comment: @Jashwant no, IE does not like `dataset` (I don't think IE9 supports it; IE10 might).  In that case you will have to use the attributes themselves and iterate over all of them.  I think it's the only way: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/DprgS/2/

Comment: so bad, jquery should not have mixed both of them.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.getDataAttr = function() {
        var attributes = {}; 
        if( this.length ) {
            $.each( this[0].attributes, function( i, attr ) {
                if( attr.name.substr(0,5) =='data-' )
                    attributes[ attr.name ] = attr.value;
            } ); 
        }
        return attributes;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

### Use

```
var data = $('div').draggable().getDataAttr();
console.log(data); // {data-name: "jashwant", data-sex: "male"}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/DprgS/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Couple more options:

Namespace your data attributes

`<div id="mydiv" data-jashwant-name="jashwant" data-jashwant-sex="male">Drag me</div>`

then loop and select only yours

```
for (var i in data) {
  if (i.indexOf('jashwant') > -1 ) { 
    console.log(i + " : " + data[i]);
  }
}
```

OR... Less reliable, but might work in this scenario. Only select data attributes whose value is a string (ignore jquery UI objects)

```
for (var i in data) {
  if (typeof data[i] === "string" ) { 
    console.log(i + " : " + data[i]);
  }
}
```